# Can't curl docker port on host - "(56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer"

Tags: docker, nginx, curl

I have looked through innumerable Stack Overflow posts on similar issues and found no resolution, or understanding of how to solve my specific problem.

On my Ubuntu VPS, I'm trying to run an nginx docker container, and I can curl the port within the container, but curling the port from the host is yielding this error.

Steps:

```
~:$ docker run -it --rm -d -p 8345:80 --name web nginx
580b5e4781e56adb9ce356892efd0d74bd0d7cad8022518cf077b3f2b203d9f6
~:$ curl http://localhost:8345
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
~:$ docker exec -it web bash
root@580b5e4781e5:/# curl http://localhost:80
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
// ...etc
</html>
root@580b5e4781e5:/# exit
exit
~:$ docker ps -a
NAMES  STATUS          IMAGE    CONTAINER ID   PORTS
web    Up 54 seconds   nginx    580b5e4781e5   0.0.0.0:8345->80/tcp, :::8345->80/tcp
~:$
```

I suspect I need to "bind" my nginx container to `0.0.0.0` - but I don't know enough about networking to figure out how to do that for this nginx image or if that even makes sense.

I use ufw (uncomplicated firewall) on this machine - and although it doesn't make sense, I have also tried `sudo ufw allow 8345` - but that doesn't really help anyway.

What am I missing?

---

Output of `telnet localhost 8345`:

```
~:$ telnet localhost 8345
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Output of netstat:

```
~:$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8345            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::8345                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

---

**Edit**

I have since realized that my docker0 network interface doesn't have access to the host or the outside world.

I spun up two alpine containers - and they can ping each other's IP address on docker0 network, but they cannot ping google.com.

I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Your `docker` command line is correct, and I'm not able to reproduce the problem you've described on my system: access to port 8345 on the host works just fine. I would start by *disabling* your firewall, restarting the docker daemon (if you manage to delete docker's firewall rules while removing everything else, restarting the daemon will re-create them), and see if the problem persists. If everything works, you've identified it as a firewall problem.

Comment: Could you please try  "telnet localhost 8345" or netstat your ports to see if the mapping is established...

Comment: @larsks ok let me try that and report back

Comment: @KemalKaplan I updated the post with the output - just says 'Connected to localhost`

Comment: It means connection is ok. Now you should check the ngnix settings...

Comment: @larsks can the firewall block network requests within the host? I thought the firewall blocks external requests? I don't understand how that works

Comment: @KemalKaplan does my netstat output look right too? And which nginx settings? I'm pulling the default image - it comes with default settings which apparently is supposed to work out of the box?

Comment: @larsks I disabled ufw, restarted docker with `sudo systemctl restart docker.service` - and then ran the above steps again - same err (56) result . I also tried a system reboot - but no luck. I've re-enabled my firewall again.

Comment: Netstat is ok but there is one more thing to check. I think the ngnix should be bind to 0.0.0.0:80 instead of 127.0.0.1:80. You can check it with netstat on your pods shell.

Comment: Hmm netstat isn't installed in that image. I tried to install netstat, but `apt-get update` failed because it couldn't fetch any of the sources. `curl -fSL archive.ubuntu.com` returned `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: You can directly check the nginx config. Be sure that the listen command cot restricted to 127.0.0.1:80. It should be 80 or *:80 or something like that.

Comment: Ah yes, `default.conf` is like this `server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    ...`

Comment: I'm convinced the problem is the docker network interface - I can't make any connections to the docker containers - and I can't make connections out of the containers either